# User cannot download Android app from Firebase App Distribution

Tags: android, firebase, google-chrome, capacitor, firebase-app-distribution

We have a capacitor application that we distribute to our testers and QA team via Firebase App Distribution. Our new QA team member cannot download the app and receives a 403 error.

`Your client does not have permission to get URL ...binaries... from this server`.

The QA eng. has turned on settings to allow app downloads from google and chrome. We have trid everything we can think of, but the problem persists. Any advice?

[image: Error Screen from App Download]

Answer (score 2):

try vpn. It`s because google is blocked few country. I am from Russia.